# parseXML returns INVALID XML in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, google-apps-script, google-caja

In a Javascript file in Google Apps Script (not Google Script but a Caja-ed Javascript), I want to parse a string to an XML document.  Outside of GAS this works:

```
$.parseXML("<root><message>Hello World</message></root>");
```

But in a GS file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xml = $.parseXML("<root><message>Hello World</message></root>");
alert(xml);
</script>
```

the parseXML claims my xml is invalid.  I assume this is something weird with whatever pre-processing GAS does to my JavaScript (Caja?).  Is there a solution?  I've tried with Jquery 1.11 and 1.9.0

Comment: maybe because it is missing `<?xml version="1.0"?>`

Comment: I tried that and it's still unhappy.  It also doesn't seem to care if you add a <!DOCTYPE root> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Caja does not support XML DOM.

If anyone is interested in what it would take to contribute such support, the main additions to the DOM taming component which would be needed are:

- Support for XML namespaces. (Currently all elements and attributes are assumed to be in the (X)HTML namespace.)
- Support for “inert” `Document`s which are not associated with a virtual frame (or in spec language, a *browsing context*). For an example of the difference, in an inert document you should be able to insert a `<html:script>` element without Caja concluding the script should be actually executed.

Comment: Thanks!  That's answers it. Quick question--where is the active code base for Caja?  Still only on code google, or is there a canonical Git repo somewhere?

Comment: Yes, Caja is hosted on Google Code SVN. The last time the topic came up there was general agreement that switching from Subversion to Git would be reasonable, but it hasn't actually happened (and would require some modifications to the workflow tools).